# OpenSSL various number packages (PSH) at connection establishment

Tags: c, ssl, tcp, openssl

I am tcpdumping a connection attempt of a client application that i've written in C. I've also written the Server in C. It depicts a TLSv1.2 Handshake and the exchange of a client certificate.

First Dump

```
21:58:54.472800 IP client.host50766 > server.host5995: Flags [S], seq 1085811090, win 14600, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 4437544 ecr 0,nop,wscale 6], length 0
21:58:54.473049 IP server.host5995 > client.host50766: Flags [S.], seq 3283511122, ack 1085811091, win 14480, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 4436964 ecr 4437544,nop,wscale 6], length 0
21:58:54.473069 IP client.host50766 > server.host5995: Flags [.], ack 1, win 229, options [nop,nop,TS val 4437544 ecr 4436964], length 0
21:58:54.473736 IP client.host50766 > server.host5995: Flags [P.], seq 1:102, ack 1, win 229, options [nop,nop,TS val 4437545 ecr 4436964], length 101
21:58:54.473843 IP server.host5995 > client.host50766: Flags [.], ack 102, win 227, options [nop,nop,TS val 4436965 ecr 4437545], length 0
**21:58:54.474478 IP server.host5995 > client.host50766: Flags [P.], seq 1:2234, ack 102, win 227, options [nop,nop,TS val 4436965 ecr 4437545], length 2233**
21:58:54.474529 IP client.host50766 > server.host5995: Flags [.], ack 2234, win 298, options [nop,nop,TS val 4437545 ecr 4436965], length 0
21:58:54.475934 IP client.host50766 > server.host5995: Flags [.], seq 102:1550, ack 2234, win 298, options [nop,nop,TS val 4437545 ecr 4436965], length 1448
21:58:54.475997 IP client.host50766 > server.host5995: Flags [P.], seq 1550:2548, ack 2234, win 298, options [nop,nop,TS val 4437545 ecr 4436965], length 998
21:58:54.476125 IP server.host5995 > client.host50766: Flags [.], ack 2548, win 303, options [nop,nop,TS val 4436965 ecr 4437545], length 0
21:58:54.478441 IP server.host5995 > client.host50766: Flags [P.], seq 2234:3324, ack 2548, win 303, options [nop,nop,TS val 4436966 ecr 4437545], length 1090
21:58:54.517533 IP client.host50766 > server.host5995: Flags [.], ack 3324, win 344, options [nop,nop,TS val 4437556 ecr 4436966], length 0
```

Second Dump

```
21:58:45.427868 IP client.host50765 > server.host5995: Flags [S], seq 76713337, win 14600, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 4435283 ecr 0,nop,wscale 6], length 0
21:58:45.428082 IP server.host5995 > client.host50765: Flags [S.], seq 2802620812, ack 76713338, win 14480, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 4434703 ecr 4435283,nop,wscale 6], length 0
21:58:45.428101 IP client.host50765 > server.host5995: Flags [.], ack 1, win 229, options [nop,nop,TS val 4435283 ecr 4434703], length 0
21:58:45.429034 IP client.host50765 > server.host5995: Flags [P.], seq 1:102, ack 1, win 229, options [nop,nop,TS val 4435283 ecr 4434703], length 101
21:58:45.429248 IP server.host5995 > client.host50765: Flags [.], ack 102, win 227, options [nop,nop,TS val 4434704 ecr 4435283], length 0
**21:58:45.429389 IP server.host5995 > client.host50765: Flags [.], seq 1:1449, ack 102, win 227, options [nop,nop,TS val 4434704 ecr 4435283], length 1448**
21:58:45.429458 IP client.host50765 > server.host5995: Flags [.], ack 1449, win 274, options [nop,nop,TS val 4435284 ecr 4434704], length 0
**21:58:45.429509 IP server.host5995 > client.host50765: Flags [P.], seq 1449:2234, ack 102, win 227, options [nop,nop,TS val 4434704 ecr 4435283], length 785**
21:58:45.429544 IP client.host50765 > server.host5995: Flags [.], ack 2234, win 319, options [nop,nop,TS val 4435284 ecr 4434704], length 0
21:58:45.431700 IP client.host50765 > server.host5995: Flags [.], seq 102:1550, ack 2234, win 319, options [nop,nop,TS val 4435284 ecr 4434704], length 1448
21:58:45.431785 IP client.host50765 > server.host5995: Flags [P.], seq 1550:2548, ack 2234, win 319, options [nop,nop,TS val 4435284 ecr 4434704], length 998
21:58:45.432803 IP server.host5995 > client.host50765: Flags [.], ack 2548, win 303, options [nop,nop,TS val 4434705 ecr 4435284], length 0
21:58:45.434776 IP server.host5995 > client.host50765: Flags [P.], seq 2234:3324, ack 2548, win 303, options [nop,nop,TS val 4434705 ecr 4435284], length 1090
21:58:45.473490 IP client.host50765 > server.host5995: Flags [.], ack 3324, win 364, options [nop,nop,TS val 4435295 ecr 4434705], length 0
```

As depicted by the ** sometimes the server sends the full package of size 2234 sometimes it dont. Why is that? Is there a way to make this behavior more constant?
I've already set

```
SSL_CTX_set_options(ctx,SSL_OP_NO_SESSION_RESUMPTION_ON_RENEGOTIATION);
SSL_CTX_set_options(ctx,SSL_OP_DONT_INSERT_EMPTY_FRAGMENTS);
```

i've also set `TCP_NODELAY` on the server socket to disable NAGLE, but it does not change anything.

I've uploaded pcap files for both cases: https://db.tt/PajbHdl3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: I don't think any longer that this is PMTU <del>I guess this is due to PMTU (Path MTU Discovery), e.g. the server determined the maximum size a packet can have without being fragmented and for further data to the same host the packets gets smaller (all packets are <= 1448 bytes).</del>

From this details I don't know why the server hello (and certificate?) sometimes get send in a single packet. Maybe you could provide more details by checking with wireshark which parts of the SSL protocol is sent in which packet.

Anyway, I don't think there should be a need to make this behavior more consistent: TCP (and SSL) are stream and not packet protocols if payload or protocol data are split in multiple TCP packets should not matter.

Comment: Its the same client, which is executed twice, why is there suddenly another MTU, the topology did not change (2 VMs running in a Host-Only network)

Comment: You are right, it has probably nothing to do with the MTU. I've updated the response - getting more details with wireshark might help to debug the issue.

Comment: i've uploaded two pcap files depicting the scenarios, see updated question.

Comment: The difference is at the boundary of a SSL message, e.g. in one case it sends Server Hello and Certificate(+others) in a single packet, in the other case it uses multiple packets, e.g. one for Server Hello and one for the rest, this one being also in two segments. From the MSS of 1460 on both pcaps I would expect any packet to have less then 1460 bytes payload, so the packet with 2299 byte is strange. If you did the tcpdump on the server side it might be related to TSO (TCP segmentation offloading), e.g. the packet inside the dump was not the packet on the wire.

Comment: In any way it is related to the TCP layer and there is nothing on the SSL layer you could do - and there is no reason anything should be done because packet size does not matter for streaming protocols.